# Можно ли зависимостях Makefile использовать пути, содержащие пробелы? Если можно, то как?

Tags: gcc, makefile

Описание каждой цели в Makefile имеет такой вид:

```
цель: зависимости через пробел
```

А что если зависимости содержат в себе пробелы? Пробовал брать их в кавычки, в апострофы, в обратные апострофы - не помогает. Или так просто нельзя делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

обратный слэш — ваш друг.

---

```
$ cat GNUmakefile 
первая\ цель: вторая\ цель
    @echo делаю $@

вторая\ цель:
    @echo делаю $@

$ make
делаю вторая цель
делаю первая цель
```

Comment: А в зависимостях точно так же можно экранировать пробел обратным слешом?

Comment: вторая строчка приведённого листинга — как раз зависимость с пробелом, экранированным обратным слэшем: `вторая\ цель`

Comment: Правда, в Windows обратный слеш - это разделитель папок, но вроде бы перед пробелом он работает как экран.

Comment: да, с разделителем путей в ms/windows хорошо наворотили: где-то прокатывает и тот и другой слэши, где-то нет. а программисты-сишники, всё ещё пользующиеся ms/windows, должны страдать: кактус есть кактус.

Comment: Да вроде бы в Linux больше страданий. Например, CodeBlocks не сохраняет список последних проектов при перезагрузке. И микрофон по-человечески не настраивается.